# Erlang Prime Factorization Using Recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang, factorization

I am trying to use prime factorization to factor a number. I want to use an if statement to test the condition and create a list if the factor is a factor. It doesn't work and I cannot think of any other way that it could work, suggestions?

```
factor( N ) ->
    if
        N rem factor(N-1) == 0 ->
            [N|factor(N-1)];
        true -> false;
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does the decomposition, but I do not use an if statement (not very common in Erlang IMHO):

```
%% this function is here to hide the detail of parameters needed for the tail recursion
decomp(N) when is_integer(N), (N > 0) -> 
    lists:reverse(decomp(N,[],2)).

%% generally in recursion the first clause is the stop condition
decomp(N,R,I) when I*I > N -> [N|R];
%% this is what you put in your if statement, is N is divided by I, then I is a factor of N
%% so add I in the list of factors and continue with (N div I) and I (it can be a multiple factor
decomp(N,R,I) when (N rem I) =:= 0 -> decomp(N div I,[I|R],I);
%% this clause is reached if I does not divide N, so simply skip it and go to 3 or I+2
decomp(N,R,2) -> decomp(N,R,3);
decomp(N,R,I) -> decomp(N,R,I+2).
```

I recorded the execution trace for one example. Notes that decomp/3 is tail recursive  so the long return phase is in fact a single return.

```
1> help_num:decomp(70610).
++ (3) <147> decomp(70610,[],2)
++ (4) <150> decomp(35305,[2],2)
++ (5) <151> decomp(35305,[2],3)
++ (6) <152> decomp(35305,[2],5)
++ (7) <150> decomp(7061,[5,2],5)
++ (8) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],7)
++ (9) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],9)
++ (10) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],11)
++ (11) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],13)
++ (12) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],15)
++ (13) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],17)
++ (14) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],19)
++ (15) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],21)
++ (16) <152> decomp(7061,[5,2],23)
++ (17) <150> decomp(307,[23,5,2],23)
-- (17) [307,23,5,2]
-- (16) [307,23,5,2]
-- (15) [307,23,5,2]
-- (14) [307,23,5,2]
-- (13) [307,23,5,2]
-- (12) [307,23,5,2]
-- (11) [307,23,5,2]
-- (10) [307,23,5,2]
-- (9) [307,23,5,2]
-- (8) [307,23,5,2]
-- (7) [307,23,5,2]
-- (6) [307,23,5,2]
-- (5) [307,23,5,2]
-- (4) [307,23,5,2]
-- (3) [307,23,5,2]
++ (3) <147> lists:reverse([307,23,5,2])
[2,5,23,307]
2>
```

Comment: Why would you initially reverse the list?

Comment: The list reverse is done at the end, when the decomposition evaluation is finished, and it is just because when I did this function I wanted to get the prime factors sorted from the smallest to the biggest. The algorithm find them in that order and put them on the head of the list in construction. This is a usual way to build list, because it avoid to make a new copy at each step; the cost to reverse at the end is less than those multiple copies.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I see two things in the code that will not work:

1. The function is supposed to return a list. Therefore the test "N rem factor(N-1) == 0" will compute the remainder of a list divided by a number, which makes no sense. You cannot perform division on a list.
2. There is a recursive call in the if guard, which is not supported.

I don't think I can help out better than that unless you explain in more detail how the code should work.

Comment: I want to use an N number and I want to return a list of all N's factors. What I was trying to do was get each number less than N and divide N by that number generating them recusively. For example, if I had 3, I would have (N-1) = 2...3/2...wouldn't divide so I would move onto the next number.

Comment: You can make recursion inside `if` statement. There is not such limitation.

Comment: In the if statement's clause bodies, yes. In the guard expressions, no. There is such a limitation.

Comment: It is not matter of `if` statements, all guards can't contain user functions. Same constrain is valid as well for function clause guards and case statement clauses guards.

Answer (score 0):

There is one implementation example. You don't have to pay attention to `next_may_be_prime/2`. You can use simple `Old + 2`. It is only optimization.

```
-module(factor).

-export([factor/1, make_wheels/0]).

factor(X) when is_integer(X), X > 0 ->
    factor(X, 2, first_primes_steps()).

factor(X, X, _) -> [X];
factor(X, Prime, Wheel) when X rem Prime =:= 0 ->
    [Prime|factor(X div Prime, Prime, Wheel)];
factor(X, Old, Wheel) when Old*Old < X ->
    {MayBePrime, Wheel2} = next_may_be_prime(Old, Wheel),
    factor(X, MayBePrime, Wheel2);
factor(X, _, _) -> [X].

%%% Prime candidates generator

next_may_be_prime(X, [Add|T]) ->
    {X+Add, case T of [] -> wheel(); _ -> T end}.

first_primes_steps() -> [1,2,2,4,2].

wheel() ->
    [4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,14,4,6,2,
     10,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,10,2,4,2,12,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,6,6,6,2,6,
     4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,6,8,6,10,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,6,10,
     2,10,2,4,2,4,6,8,4,2,4,12,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,12,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,
     2,4,6,2,6,10,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,6,6,2,6,6,4,6,6,
     2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,6,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,4,2,10,2,6,4,2,4,
     2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,8,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,
     4,6,6,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,6,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,
     6,6,8,4,2,6,10,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,10,6,2,4,8,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,6,
     2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,6,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,
     6,4,8,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,10,2,
     4,6,8,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,6,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,6,6,2,6,6,
     4,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,10,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,
     12,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,12,4,2,4,8,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,6,2,4,6,2,6,4,
     2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,10,6,8,6,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,6,4,6,2,
     6,4,2,4,2,10,12,2,4,2,10,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,10,2,6,4,14,4,2,4,
     2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,12,2,12].

%%% Auxiliary functions for making prime wheels

make_wheels() ->
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Primes = [2,3,5,7,11],
    Next = 13,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Period = lists:foldl(fun(X, A) -> X*A end, 1, Primes),
    Max = Period + Next,
    F = fun(X, A) -> array:set(X, false, A) end,
    G = fun(X, A) -> lists:foldl(F, A, lists:seq(X, Max, X)) end,
    Sieve = lists:foldl(G, array:new([{default, true}]), Primes),
    {
        diffs(Primes ++ [Next]),
        diffs([ X || X <- lists:seq(Next, Max), array:get(X, Sieve)])
        }.

diffs([H|T]) ->
    diffs(H, T).

diffs(_, []) -> [];
diffs(A, [B|T]) -> [B-A|diffs(B, T)].
```